# LinkedIn Developer Application - How to update a Company Name for Application API?

Tags: linkedin-api

**Problem:** At https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps The "company name" is provided as a header for my application, and there is no edit possibility for editing the "company name".
Any idea how I can do that?

Sorry for this simple question. but it really annoys me!

**Background:**
I use spring social api to provide linkedIn login for a web application.
We found a new company and I would prefer to be consistent and update the company name in linkedIn App as well.

**What I tried:**
I tried to create a new Application, with the correct company name. The problem I got was the "provider-user-id" returned from linkedIn Auth 2.0 for the registered user changes. so all the old users are recognised and registered as a new user!

Answer (score 1):

There is presently no facility for changing your application's company name.  Creating a new application is the right way to go, in this case - however as you encountered, that will generate a unique new set of user IDs for each authenticated user, so they will have to re-authenticate, and your system will recognize them as different people.